# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, sql, pdo

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '") VALUES ()' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\userv2.php:120 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\userv2.php(120): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\create.php(41): User->Save() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\userv2.php on line 120

we used back tick for the column name as it was suggested in few of the post here but it doesn't solve the error completely. i read similar post but couldn't find the solution so i am poting the error and code for your help. thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

/*
 * mmber variable decleration...
 */
class User {
    private $ID;
    private $objPDO;
    private $strTableName;
    private $arRelationMap;
    private $blForDeletion;



    private $FirstName;
    private $LastName;
    private $Username;
    private $Password;
    private $EmailAddress;

    private $DateLastLogin;
    private $TimeLastLogin;
    private $DateAccountCreated;
    private $TimeAccountCreated;

    //constructor is use for initialisation for the object
    public function __construct(PDO $objPDO, $id = NULL) {
        $this->strTableName = `system_user`;
        $this->arRelationMap = array(
            `id` => "ID",
            `first_name` => "FirstName",
            `last_name` => "LastName",
            `username` => "Username",
            `md5_pw` => "Password",
            `email_address` => "EmailAddress",
            `date_last_login` => "DateLastLogin",
            `time_last_login` => "TimeLastLogin",
            `date_account_created` => "DateAccountCreated",
            `time_account_created` => "TimeAccountCreated");






            $this->objPDO =$objPDO;
                if (isset($id)) {
                    $this->ID = $id;
                    $strQuery = "SELECT ";
                    foreach ($this->arRelationMap as $key => $value) {
                        $strQuery .= "\"" . $key . "\",";
                    }
                   $strQuery = substr($strQuery, 0, strlen($strQuery)-1);
                   $strQuery .=  "FROM"  . $this->strTableName . " WHERE \"id\" = :eid";
                   $objStatement = $this->objPDO->prepare($strQuery);
                   $objStatement->bindparam(' :eid', $this->ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                   $objStatement->execute();
                   $arRow = $objStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                   foreach($arRow as $key => $value) {
                       $strMember = $this->arRelationMap[$key];
                       if(property_exists($this, $strMember)) {
                           if (is_numeric($value)) {
                               eval('$this->' . $strMember . ' = ' . $value . ';');
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               eval('$this->' . $strMember . ' = "' . $value . '";');
                           };
                       };

                };
    };

}







       public function Save() {
        if (!isset($this->ID)) {
             $strValueList = "";
     $strQuery = 'INSERT INTO "' . $this->strTableName . '"(';
     foreach ($this->arRelationMap as $key => $value) {
            eval('$actualVal = &$this->' . $value .';');
                    if(isset($actualVal)){
                    var_dump($actualVal);
                    $strQuery .= '"' . $key . '", ';
                    $strValueList .= ":$value, ";

        } ; 
            }        






        $strQuery = substr($strQuery, 0, strlen($strQuery) - 2);
     $strValueList = substr($strValueList, 0, strlen($strValueList) - 2);
     $strQuery .= ") VALUES (";
     $strQuery .= $strValueList;
     $strQuery .= ")";
     unset($objStatement);
     $objStatement = $this->objPDO->prepare($strQuery);
     foreach ($this->arRelationMap as $key => $value){
         eval('$actualVal = &$this->' . $value . ';');
         if (isset($actualVal)){
             if ((is_int($actualVal)) || ($actualVal == NULL)) {
                       $objStatement->bindValue(':' . $value, $actualVal, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     $objStatement->bindValue(':' . $value, $actualVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                    };
                };
         }
         $objStatement->execute();
         $this->ID = $this->objPDO->lastInsertId($this->strTableName . "_id_seq");

         }
     }
```

Comment: Could you please echo out `$strQuery` just prior to the prepare statement?

Comment: OK first of all: `eval()` is evil! And in the context you are using it, it is completely unnecessary, you can simply do `$this->$strMember = $value;` and it will work fine. Secondly, using backticks is a good idea, but you have done it wrong. The backticks should be part of the PHP string, not used to quote it. e.g. `\`name\`` becomes `'\`name\`'` You have also not used it to quote the field names in statements, e.g. `$strQuery .= "\"" . $key . "\",";` should be `$strQuery .= "\`" . $key . "\`,";` and `" WHERE \"id\" = :eid"` should be `" WHERE \`id\` = :eid"`

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax for a MySQL INSERT is :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2,col3) VALUES(15,col1*2,'string');
```

And not :

```
INSERT INTO "tbl_name" ("col1","col2","col3") VALUES(15,col1*2,'string');
```